# How to send emails using RabbitMq and Django

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I am new to RabbitMQ at the same time, if possible would someone also link me to a good tutorial for my task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial for setup:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html#installing-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-1604

More on RabbitMQ installation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

After setting up you can send email creating a celery task.

ref: https://medium.com/@juwelariful1/send-mail-in-django-with-gmail-and-smtp-include-celery-and-gmail-configuration-4b07ae4f8542

More info on django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMultiAlternatives

@shared_task
def send_email_to(subject, body, from_email, to_email):
    try:
        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, [to_email])
        email.content_subtype = 'html'
        email.send()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I have followed the docs to the letter but I still can't get it working is there anything you can helpme with, I spent hours on this with no progress

Comment: Can you be more specific on which point you are having trouble..

Comment: Nvm finally got it